# Load data in renderArgs for 404 & 500 errors

Tags: templates, playframework, http-status-code-404

Using Play Framework, I was wondering if it was possible to load some vars in the template like I do in other controllers.

I mainly think about my "STATIC_URL" var that contains the path to the static files, that changes between my DEV/PROD modes.

Or at least, which alternatives I can use to make this works?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear and could do with an example of what you are trying to achieve.
However if what I think you are asking is correct try the following in your controller:

```
//This will run before any controler request is called
@Before
static void globals() {
    renderArgs.put("staticUrl", staticUrl);//Adds staticUrl object to the renderArgs map.
}
```

Then in your template use **${staticUrl}** to access the value from the renderArgs map.

Comment: Excuse me for not being clear. I'm already doing this kind of calls (Before & After) but they aren't called when a 404 or 500 error occurs, since those errors doesn't go into my Controllers, thus not into my Before & After methods. I'd like to inject the "staticUrl" var in the 404 & 500 rendering page.

Comment: The method annotated with @before should still be invoked. If you have any doubt try logging some debug statement whilst looking up a non existing resource.

Comment: If you want to tap into lay lifecycle, consider creating a Plugin http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2/play/PlayPlugin.html